# Video not saving in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm passing a video as input, and the grabbed video is the output. the output is showing in the window but at the end its throwing an attribute error and video file is saving with the given name but its an empty file.

I went through many questions similar to this, and I tried all those answers  but the output was same. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in this code?

```
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
            help="path to the (optional) video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


lower = np.array([0, 0, 20], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([25, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")


if not args.get("video", False):
   camera = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/15-IMG_1090.MOV')

   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
   out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))


else:
   camera = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/15-IMG_1093.MOV')

   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
   out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))


 while True:
   # grab the current frame
   (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

   if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
      break


   # resize the frame, convert it to the HSV color space,
   # and determine the HSV pixel intensities that fall into
   # the speicifed upper and lower boundaries

   frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
   converted = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   skinMask = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)


   kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
   skinMask = cv2.erode(skinMask, kernel, iterations=2)
   skinMask = cv2.dilate(skinMask, kernel, iterations=2)


   skinMask = cv2.GaussianBlur(skinMask, (3, 3), 0)
   skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=skinMask)


   out.write(skin)
   cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([frame, skin]))

   # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
      break


camera.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Harshitha/python learning/python/video_analysis/new_code_grab.py", line 60, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
  File "C:\Users\Harshitha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Please anyone help me to fix the error and to save the new grabbed video.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your "frame" in camera.read() is None. Can you confirm it is indeed none? Can you print camera.open() before camera.read() line and see if it true or false? You may find several resources online if this is False. This could be due to incompatible installation of opencv+python, ffmpeg or unsupported format.

Comment: I have printed the frame, the values are printing but at the end its showing none . Camera is also printing the value. Even I have printed 'grabbed' too, that will come true until the end, at last as i said the frame will become none, and the grabbed will become false.

Comment: If you have grabbed as false, then it will not go to line "imutils.resize(frame, width=500)". what is value of args.get("video")? is it true?

Comment: Yes its true, but by the end of the video its going wrong, its giving false. Till the end the video is playing correctly, while ending its throwing an error. And even i have tried by removing "if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
      break", but also the same error.

Comment: does adding "if frame is None: break" after "if args.get("video") and not grabbed: break" line work? well, clearly, your error is coming because frame is None.

Comment: Okay, now how to get off from that None and save the result video?? What  should i need to change?